# Uninstall teradata ulitilies issue

Tags: teradata

I am trying to install teradata utilities 15.x,

I earlier installed teradata ODBC drive and .NET Data Provider for teradata.

Now if I start the installation, I get an error saying:

***"The installation failed for the following reason:
A TTU 14.0 suite is installed. Please uninstall all TTU 14.10 suites before installing TTU 15.00"***

I tried to uninstall the suite using uninstall_TTU.vbs, but I get below error:

***TTUSuiteSilent.exe was not found in .\TTU directory.
This script needs TTUSuiteSilent.exe to remove suite packages.
Aborting uninstallation....***

Any advise on how to get this uninstalled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Teradata ODBC driver typically requires three components to be installed on the client:

1. ICU Libraries
2. GSS Libraries
3. ODBC Driver

You must ensure that all three of these have been removed before you can replace them with another version. Typically, they can be found in the Add/Remove Programs applet of the Windows Control Panel.